# Node.js HTTP - Request not expected. What's this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

It seems that when I tried accessing a URL via get, instead
of returning a string, it returned nothing.
Then the received header has a location: (url) thing. What is causing
this man!

See the console.log() below.
My requested URL is chatcoding.net/ajax/getcode.php?secretkey&sid=secrethash

but it seems that I receive a header-location thingy. Why?

```
        headers:
  { location: 'http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=chatcoding%2Enet%2Fajax%2
  Fgetcode%2Ephp%3Fsecretkey%26
  sid%3Dsecrethash',
```

Why the HECK is it redirecting me to that URL!?
I need answers everyone. Thank you!

Comment: Uppercase words and the general tone of you question probably will not help you getting better answers here.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your code, but your network configuration.  Your network administrator is using OpenDNS with a device that is intercepting your HTTP requests.

See also:  https://www.opendns.com/business-security/